# Java sort 4 arrays into 1 array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to efficiently sort through 4 arrays and return 2 results.
The first result will contain all numbers that exist in the arrays.
The second result will contain, all occurrences of each number in the result

```
int[] a = [1,2,3,4,5];
int[] b = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
int[] c = [1,3,7];
int[] d = [2,3,4,8,9,10];


 int[] result1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

int[] result2 = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

Comment: Have you heard of Arrays.sort()?

Comment: That's great. I suggest you start coding then.

Comment: First merge them all and sort (result2), then copy and remove duplicates (result1).

Comment: You could try implement merge sort of all 4 arrays at once for better effieciently.

Comment: As @Fincio said, you could implement a merge sort. If the input is already sorted, you only need to use the merging part.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys and answers. Mena thanks for your advice an direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step 1: Combine all the arrays
- Step 2: Sort arrays using  `Arrays.sort(array);`
- Step 3: Remove the duplicates.

  ```
  int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
  int[] b = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  int[] c = {1,3,7};
  int[] d = {2,3,4,8,9,10};

  int[] resultArray1 = new int[a.length+b.length+c.length+d.length];
  int arrayIndex = 0;

  for (int i=0; i< a.length ; i++, arrayIndex++ )
  {
      resultArray1[arrayIndex] = a[i];
  }
  for (int i=0; i< b.length ; i++, arrayIndex++ )
  {
      resultArray1[arrayIndex] = b[i];
  }   
  for (int i=0; i< c.length ; i++, arrayIndex++ )
  {
      resultArray1[arrayIndex] = c[i];
  }           
  for (int i=0; i< d.length ; i++, arrayIndex++ )
  {
      resultArray1[arrayIndex] = d[i];
  }       

  // Sorting Arrays   
  System.out.println("Array before Sort"+Arrays.toString(resultArray1));
  Arrays.sort(resultArray1);
  System.out.println("Array after Sort"+Arrays.toString(resultArray1));


  // Removing duplicates
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
  for (int i = 0; i < resultArray1.length; i++) {
      set.add(""+resultArray1[i]); // To convert to string
  }

  String[] uniqueStringArray = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]); ;
  int [] uniqueIntArray = new int [uniqueStringArray.length];

  // Converting string array to int array
  for(int i=0;i<uniqueStringArray.length;i++)
  {
      uniqueIntArray[i]= Integer.parseInt(uniqueStringArray[i]);
  }
  Arrays.sort(uniqueIntArray);
  System.out.println("Unique Array after Sort"+Arrays.toString(uniqueIntArray));
  ```

**Output:**

```
Array before Sort[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10]
Array after Sort[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Unique Array after Sort[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

- Combine all 4 arrays in 1 array
- sort Array
- Remove Dublicate from array

  ```
  import java.util.Vector;

  class sort
  {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] b = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int[] c = {1,3,7};
    int[] d = {2,3,4,8,9,10};
    int[] s = combine(a,b,c,d); //concate array using concate function 
    int[] sort = sort(s);//sort array using sort function 
    //SORTING ARRAY
    System.out.print("ARRAY AFTER SORT  ");
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i=0;i<sort.length;i++)
    {
     if(i==sort.length-1)
        System.out.print(sort[i]);
     else
        System.out.print(sort[i]+",");
     }
     System.out.println("]\n");


    //REMOVE DUPLICATE 
    int[] removedups=removedups(sort);// Remove Duplicate item from array using removedups
    System.out.print("ARRAY REMOVE DUPLICATE  ");
    System.out.print("[");
    for(int i=0;i<removedups.length;i++)
    {
      if(i==removedups.length-1)
          System.out.print(removedups[i]);
      else
          System.out.print(removedups[i]+",");
      }
       System.out.print("]");
    }
       public static int[] combine(int a[],int b[],int c[],int d[])//combine array 
      {
      int sort []=new int[a.length+b.length+c.length+d.length];
      int j=0;
      for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
      {
      sort[j]=a[i];
      j++;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
     {
      sort[j]=b[i];
      j++;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
     {
       sort[j]=c[i];
        j++;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++)
     {
      sort[j]=d[i];
      j++;
     }
     return sort;
   }
   public static int[] sort(int s[]) // sort array 
   {
   int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
     {
       for(int j=i+1;j<s.length-1;j++)
         {
          if(s[i]>s[j])
          { 
              temp=s[i];
              s[i]=s[j];
              s[j]=temp;
            }
         }
       }
        return s;
   }
   public static int[] removedups(int s[])//remove dups from sorted array
   {
      Vector array=new Vector();
      int l=0;
      for(int i=0;i<s.length-1;i++)
       {
      if(s[i]!=s[i+1])
         {
          array.add(s[i]);
          l++;
         }
     }
   int[] temp=new int[array.size()];
   for(int j=0;j<temp.length;j++)
     {
        temp[j]=Integer.parseInt(""+array.get(j));
      }
     return temp ;

        }
     }//end the program
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Simpliest way is use `sort` and `HashSet`

```
public class SortClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Define imput data
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        int[] c = {1, 3, 7};
        int[] d = {2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10};

        //Actual algorithm
        List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        all.addAll(toList(a));
        all.addAll(toList(b));
        all.addAll(toList(c));
        all.addAll(toList(d));

        Collections.sort(all);

        TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        set.addAll(all);

        int[] sorted = toIntArray(all);
        int[] sortedUniq = toIntArray(set);

        //Output result
        System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(sorted));
        System.out.println("Sorted uniq: " + Arrays.toString(sortedUniq));
    }

    // We need pair of method to convert between `int[]` and `Collection<Integer>`
    private static int[] toIntArray(Collection<Integer> all) {
        int[] ints = new int[all.size()];
        int i =0;
        for (int val : all) {
            ints[i] = val;
            i++;
        }
        return ints;
    }

    private static Collection<? extends Integer> toList(int[] ints) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i : ints) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

But if performance is critical we can utilize the fact that input arrays already sorted and us merge sort:

```
public class SortClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        int[] b = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
        int[] c = {1, 3, 7};
        int[] d = {2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10};

        //Prepare data structure
        List<ArrayTail> all = new ArrayList<ArrayTail>();
        add(all, new ArrayTail(a));
        add(all, new ArrayTail(b));
        add(all, new ArrayTail(c));
        add(all, new ArrayTail(d));

        int[] sorted = sort(all);

        int[] sortedUniq = getUniq(sorted);

        System.out.println("Sorted: " + Arrays.toString(sorted));
        System.out.println("Sorted uniq: " + Arrays.toString(sortedUniq));
    }

    private static int[] getUniq(int[] sorted) {
        Collection<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int current = sorted[0];
        result.add(current);
        for (int i : sorted){
            if(i != current){
                current = i;
                result.add(i);
            }
        }
        return toIntArray(result);
    }

    private static int[] sort(List<ArrayTail> all) {
        int totalLength = 0;
        for (ArrayTail tail : all){
            totalLength+=tail.size();
        }
        int[] result = new int[totalLength];
        int pos = 0;

        while(!all.isEmpty()){
            //Take smallest value from smallest array
            ArrayTail smallest = all.get(0);
            result[pos] = smallest.take();
            pos++;

            // remove array if no more elements in it
            if(smallest.size() ==0){
                all.remove(0);
            } else {
                // ensure that first element steel smallest
                sortFirstElement(all);
            }

        }

        return result;
    }

    // This is actually on step of bubble sort, but it
    // works because all other list except may be first already sorted
    private static void sortFirstElement(List<ArrayTail> all) {
        for (int i = 0; i < all.size()-1; i++) {
            if(all.get(i).get() > all.get(i+1).get()){
                Collections.swap(all, i, i + 1);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void add(List<ArrayTail> all, ArrayTail arrayTail) {
        // all sorted here  
        all.add(0, arrayTail);
        sortFirstElement(all);
        // all sorted here, again  
    }

    private static int[] toIntArray(Collection<Integer> all) {
        int[] ints = new int[all.size()];
        int i =0;
        for (int val : all) {
            ints[i] = val;
            i++;
        }
        return ints;
    }

    // Simpl data structure representing tail of array
    private static class ArrayTail {
        private final int[] arr;
        private int pos;

        public ArrayTail(int[] arr) {
            this.arr = arr;
            this.pos = 0;
        }

        public int size() {
            return arr.length - pos;
        }

        public int take() {
            return arr[pos++];
        }

        public int get() {
            return arr[pos];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see code become more complex but possible work faster.

PS: fun thing is that bubble sort can be used in real life :)

Answer (score 0):

TRY Using merge sort algorithm. wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Answer (score 0):

For result 1, dump the contents of your 4 lists into a TreeSet. This will sort and remove duplicates from the set at the same time. Then get the array of the set.

For result 2, use array copy to copy all the numbers into 1 array and then sort that array using Arrays.sort(...). There is no need to try to merge them on your own due to the nature of the sorting algorithm which is O(nlog(n)). Quadrupling the size results in a multiplying factor of only 2.